# jQuery Dual Range Slider Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build an dual range slider in jQuery by my own.
My first attempt kind of works. But sometimes if I release the mouse button after dragging a slide the website automatically reloads.
I've uploaded my Code on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/u2d8P

Here is the js part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $dragging = null;

    $('.slider').bind("mousemove", function(e) {
        if ($dragging) {
            if (e.pageX<200) {
                $dragging.offset({
                    left: e.pageX
                });
            }

        }
   });

    $('.left_slider').bind("mousedown", function (e) {
        $dragging = $(e.target);
    });

    $('.right_slider').bind("mousedown", function (e) {
        $dragging = $(e.target);
    });

    $('.slider').bind("mouseup", function (e) {
        $dragging = null;
    });
});
```

Even in the fiddle it reloads sometimes after releasing the mouse button.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Greetz

Comment: Please use the TidyUp button in your fiddles and follow the suggestions. It makes your demo simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your anchors (do they even need to be anchors?) have no `href` value (which is invalid, btw), the default action is to reload the current page. You'd need to either use `preventDefault` to stop that, or use a value such as `#` or `javascript:void(0)`.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u2d8P/1/

```
<a href="#" class="left_slider"></a>
<a href="#" class="right_slider"></a>
```

---

Here's how you'd do it using `preventDefault`. Credit to Joe Cullinan.

http://jsfiddle.net/hPkS6

Comment: This is the best solution, but if , for some reason, you wanted to apply an `href` to one of these buttons, here's a [JSFiddle using e.preventDefault()](http://jsfiddle.net/hPkS6/).


Basically, after your mouseup/mousedown events fire off, the default events fire. In this case, since the clickable objects are `<a>`s, after your mouseup/mousedown they will cause the browser to navigate. 

By putting e.preventDefault() in the event handler, you're instructing the browser to stop any subsequent events from firing as a result of the event "bubbling up".